# How to prevent triggering mouseleave after mouseup?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

In my Javascript app I am having issues with event bubbling, namely I would like not to trigger `mouseleave` after mouse up on an element (have implemented dragging behavior therefore it moves and mouse leaves it).

How can I do that ?

**EDIT**

I am using `d3.js` to capture event in the following way :

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
        .on("mouseover", function(d,i){
        ...
        }
        .on("mouseup", function(d,i){
        ...
        }
        .on("mouseleave", function(d,i){
        ...
        }
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries, do you have a sample of the code you are using? These things are all helpful to know.

Comment: `var dragging = false; function mouseLeave(e){ if (dragging) return; ... }`?

Comment: @ars265 I have added this info in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it in similar way to user1671639's adivice with boolean check :

```
var been_in_mouseup = false;

.on("mousedown", function(d){
    ...
    been_in_mouseup = false;
})
.on("mouseup", function(d,i){
    ...
    been_in_mouseup = true;
})
.on("mouseleave", function(d, i){
    ...
    if(false == been_in_mouseup )
    {
    ...
    }
})
```

**EDIT**

Is there any more elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

How about having a **boolean `check`** variable like this

```
var preventBubble = true;
d3.selectAll("circle")
        .on("mouseover", function(d,i){
        ...
        }
        .on("mouseup", function(d,i){
        preventBubble = false;
        ....
        }
        .on("mouseleave", function(d,i){

        if(preventBubble) {         
        ...
          }
        }
```

Instead of using `mouseover` and `mouseleave`, I would prefer to use **`.hover()` with callback**

```
d3.selectAll("circle").on("hover", function(d,i){
    //To Dos
  }, function(d,i) {
    // callback To Dos
});
```